# ACPI BIOS Error (bug)

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, hp, bios, acpi

Hi I have a HP Omen laptop, when I unplug/plug the battery charger this is error happens and my nvidia graphics clock will then be limited to 303 Mhz for it to go back normally I have to reboot my system, also updating my bios did not resolve this. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```
[ 2853.943762] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q37.POWS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[ 2853.943792] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q37]
[ 2853.943796] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q37]
[ 2853.943804] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q37 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[ 2853.944197] hp_wmi: bad event status 0x5
[ 2860.087524] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q37.POWS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psargs-330)
[ 2860.087547] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q37]
[ 2860.087549] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q37]
[ 2860.087556] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._Q37 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
[ 2860.087841] hp_wmi: bad event status 0x5
```

Comment: Any progress on solving? I have a similar error on Acer Nitro 5 laptop.